# javascript canvas draw multiple rectangles around a circle facing the centre

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, trigonometry, angle

I am looking for a way to draw multiple rectangles around a circle at an angle facing the centre. What i have so far, currently just drawing the rectangles around a circle facing one direction lacking the angle inclination towards the centre -

https://thysultan.com/projects/thyplayer/

What i want is for the rectangles to incline at an angle such that each rectangle is facing the centre of the circle at it's designated position. 
How would one do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Trigonometry approach

To animate the lines towards the center you can use either transforms or trigonometry math. Personally I find it easier with math in cases like this so here is such an example.

See @markE's answer for an example on how to use transforms (transforms can be easier on the eye and in the code in general).

**Some prerequisites:**

- We know canvas is oriented so that a 0° angle points towards right. This is essential if you want to mark the frequency range somehow.
- We need to calculate the length of the line from outer radius towards center (inner radius)
- We need to calculate the end points of the line based on the angle.

An easy solution can be to make a function that calculates a single line at a center `(cx, cy)` at a certain `angle` (in radians), with `t` as length, t being in the range [0, 1] (as the FFT floating point buffer bins). We also provide an outer and inner radius to enable limiting the line:

```
function getLine(cx, cy, angle, t, oRadius, iRadius) {

    var radiusDiff = oRadius - iRadius,            // calc radius diff to get max length
        length = radiusDiff * t;                   // now we have the line length

    return {
        x1: oRadius * Math.cos(angle),             // x1 point (outer)
        y1: oRadius * Math.sin(angle),             // y1 point (outer)
        x2: (oRadius - length) * Math.cos(angle),  // x2 point (inner)
        y2: (oRadius - length) * Math.sin(angle)   // y2 point (inner)
    }
}
```

All we need to do now is to feed it data from the FFT analyzer.

NB: Since all lines points towards center, you will have a crowded center area. Something to have in mind when determine the line widths and inner radius as well as number of bins to use.

## Example demo

For the example I will just use some random data for the "FFT" and plot 64 bins.

```js
// angle - in radians
function getLine(cx, cy, angle, t, oRadius, iRadius) {

  var radiusDiff = oRadius - iRadius,            // calc radius diff to get max length
      length = radiusDiff * t;                   // now we have the line length

  return {
    x1: cx + oRadius * Math.cos(angle),             // x1 point (outer)
    y1: cy + oRadius * Math.sin(angle),             // y1 point (outer)
    x2: cx + (oRadius - length) * Math.cos(angle),  // x2 point (inner)
    y2: cy + (oRadius - length) * Math.sin(angle)   // y2 point (inner)
  }
}

// calculate number of steps based on bins
var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d"),
    fftLength = 64,
    angleStep = Math.PI * 2 / fftLength,
    angle = 0,
    line;

ctx.beginPath();                                    // not needed in demo, but when animated

while(angle < Math.PI*2) {
  // our line function in action:
  line = getLine(250, 250, angle, getFFT(), 240, 50);
  
  ctx.moveTo(line.x1, line.y1);                    // add line to path
  ctx.lineTo(line.x2, line.y2);
  angle += angleStep                               // get next angle
}

ctx.lineWidth = 5;                                 // beware of center area
ctx.stroke();                                      // stroke all lines at once

// to smooth the "FFT" random data
function getFFT() {return Math.random() * 0.16 + 0.4}
```

```html
<canvas width=500 height=500></canvas>
```